# How to paint over a bitmap with a brush - C#/.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, paint

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't seem to find any way to do it.  I have a custom WinForms control that has an overridden paint method that does some custom drawing.

I have a Bitmap in memory, and all I want to do is paint over the whole thing with a HashBrush, but preserve the alpha channel, so that the transparent parts of the bitmap don't get painted.

The bitmap in memory is not a simple shape, so it will not be feasible to define it as a set of paths or anything.

EDIT:  In response to showing the code, there is a lot of code in the paint routine, so I'm only including a relevant snippet, which is the method in question.  This method gets called from the main paint override.  It accepts a list of images which are black transparency masks and combines them into one, then it uses a ColorMatrix to change the color of the combined image it created, allowing it to be overlayed on top of the background.  All I want to accomplish is being able to also paint hashmarks on top of it.

```
    private void PaintSurface(PaintEventArgs e, Image imgParent, List<Image> surfImgs, Rectangle destRect, ToothSurfaceMaterial material)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgParent.Width, imgParent.Height,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
        {

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                foreach (Image img in surfImgs)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(img, System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
                }
            }

            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(
                new float[][] {
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0.7f, 0},
                    new float[] { material.R / 255.0f,
                                  material.G / 255.0f,
                                  material.B / 255.0f,
                                  0, 1}
                  });

            ImageAttributes imageAttr = new ImageAttributes();
            imageAttr.SetColorMatrix(matrix);

            Rectangle r = GetSizedRect(imgParent, destRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,
                                 r,
                                 0,
                                 0,
                                 bmp.Width,
                                 bmp.Height,
                                 GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code your using.

Comment: @DonA Edited original post to include the method I'm working on.

Comment: Where is the `HashBrush` part since that is part of the question? Also in your loop for `surfImgs` you are drawing to the same location - is that right?

Comment: @DonA the OP possibly meant `HatchBrush`

Comment: Typo ?  Maybe ???????

Comment: could you explain a little on what the `ColorMatrix` does here? looking at its `definition` is not easy to know what's it for. BTW, reading your problem description, I can understand it a little BUT reading your code, I'm totally lost. Your code **doesn't even** relate to any the so-called `HatchBrush`?

Comment: @DonA Yes, sorry, I meant HatchBrush.  And yes, the surfImgs all get combined into one "mask", the result being an amorphous black shape on a transparent background (it's used to map anatomical regions).  The HatchBrush code is not present, because I'm not sure how/where to apply it, hence the question.

Comment: @KingKing Per my comment above, I use the ColorMatrix to change the black "mask" into whatever color is passed in, with 70% alpha.  It's then drawn on top of the background image (a medical illustration of a tooth).  The result is to highlight anatomical regions with a particular color.  But, in addition to the solid color, I need to also show hatches (not hashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was the following method.  First I combine the individual masks into one, then create a new Bitmap and paint the whole thing with the HatchBrush, finally iterate through the mask and set the alpha values on the newly generated bitmap based on the mask.

```
    private Bitmap GenerateSurface(Image imgParent, List<Image> surfImgs, ToothSurfaceMaterial material)
    {
        Bitmap mask = new Bitmap(imgParent.Width, imgParent.Height,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mask))
        {
            foreach (Image img in surfImgs)
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            }
        }

        Bitmap output = new Bitmap(mask.Width, mask.Height,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(output))
        {
            if (material.HatchStyle != null)
            {
                HatchBrush hb = new HatchBrush((HatchStyle)material.HatchStyle, material.FgColor, material.BgColor);
                g.FillRectangle(hb, new Rectangle(0, 0, output.Width, output.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(material.FgColor);
                g.FillRectangle(sb, new Rectangle(0, 0, output.Width, output.Height));
            }

        }

        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, output.Width, output.Height);
        var bitsMask = mask.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bitsOutput = output.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        unsafe
        {
            int offset = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* ptrMask = (byte*)bitsMask.Scan0 + y * bitsMask.Stride;
                byte* ptrOutput = (byte*)bitsOutput.Scan0 + y * bitsOutput.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < mask.Width; x++)
                {
                    offset = 4 * x + 3;
                    ptrOutput[offset] = (byte)(ptrMask[offset] * 0.7);
                }
            }
        }
        mask.UnlockBits(bitsMask);
        output.UnlockBits(bitsOutput);

        return output;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any `ColorMatrix` which is *overkill*, you just need a `ColorMap`, here is the code which may not suit your requirement but should give you the idea. That's because I possibly don't understand your problem well, if you have any problem, just leave some comment and I'll try to improve the answer:

```
ImageAttributes imgA = new ImageAttributes();
ColorMap cm = new ColorMap();
cm.OldColor = Color.Black
cm.NewColor = Color.FromArgb((byte)(0.7*255), Color.Green);
imgA.SetRemapTable(new ColorMap[] {cm });         
GraphicsUnit gu = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;   
g.DrawImage(imageToDraw,new Point[]{Point.Empty, 
                                    new Point(backImage.Width/2,0), 
                                    new Point(0,backImage.Height/2)},
                        Rectangle.Round(imageToDraw.GetBounds(ref gu)), 
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgA);
```

the `new Point[]` is an array of 3 `Points` used to locate the destination Rectangle.
The code above is used to **Draw the `imageToDraw` on top of the `backImage`** and convert and color of `Black` to the color `Green` with `Opacity = 70%`. That's what you want to fulfill your code.

### UPDATE

This may be what you want, in fact **your code doesn't show what you want**, it just shows what you have which doesn't implement anything related to your problem now. I deduce this from your very first description in your question. The input is an image with background color (which will be made partially transparent later) being `Black`. Now the output you want is an image with all the non-Black region being painted with a `HatchBrush`. This output will then be processed to turn the `Black` background to a `partially transparent` background.

```
public void PaintHatchBrush(Bitmap input, HatchBrush brush){
   using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(input)){
      g.Clip = GetForegroundRegion(input, Color.Black);
      GraphicsUnit gu = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
      g.FillRectangle(brush, input.GetBounds(ref gu));
   }
}
//This is implemented using `GetPixel` which is not fast, but it gives you the idea.
public Region GetForegroundRegion(Bitmap input, Color backColor){
  GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
      Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Empty;          
      bool jumpedIn = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < bm.Height; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < bm.Width; j++) {
             Color c = bm.GetPixel(j, i);
             if (c != backColor&&!jumpedIn) {
                 rect = new Rectangle(j, i, 1, 1);                        
                 jumpedIn = true;
             }
             if (jumpedIn && (c == backColor || j == bm.Width - 1)) {
                 rect.Width = j - rect.Left;
                 gp.AddRectangle(rect);
                 jumpedIn = false;
             }
          }
      }
      return new Region(gp);
}
//Usage
HatchBrush brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent30, Color.Green, Color.Yellow);
PaintHatchBrush(yourImage, brush);
//then yourImage will have HatchBrush painted on the surface leaving the Black background intact.
//This image will be used in the next process to turn the Black background into 70%
//opacity background as you did using ColorMatrix (or more simply using ColorMap as I posted previously)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but there isn't any problem with the current code as far as achieving the result of painting a translucent color over an image.  Your solution does indeed offer an alternate method of accomplishing that, but doesn't solve the problem of needing to also fill the mask with a HatchBrush.

Comment: @amnesia it's better if you post some screen shot of what you want. BTW, I don't really understand what the `mask region` refers to, is it the `Black region` or anything else?

Comment: @amnesia see my update if it's what you want, as I said, your problem in fact could have been described clearly with just 1 or 2 screen shots.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was tied up with other things.  I posted the solution I used, thank you for your efforts, your code is similar to what I ended up doing.